# How Can I Use Regex to Match All the Urls in This String?

Tags: javascript, regex

I hope to use the following code to get all URLs from a string.

But I only the three URLs ,there are `http://www.google.com`, `https://www.twitter.com`  and `www.msn.com`.

I hope I can get all URLs include `bing.com` in the result, how can I modifty the `var expression =  /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.| ...` ?

```
function openURLs() {
    let links = "http://www.google.com  Hello https://www.twitter.com The  www.msn.com  World bing.com";   

    if (links) {
        var expression = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;

        var url_array = links.match(expression);

        if (url_array != null) {
            url_array.forEach((url) => {
                urlOK = url.match(/^https?:/) ? url : '//' + url;
                window.open(urlOK)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does every url end in `.com` or could it be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of what you currently have, you can just append `|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}` to the end of your expression. The resulting line will look like this:

```
var expression = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}/gi;
```

This could be cleaner, but it'll do what you're asking.

Edit:

If you're okay with something slightly more permissive that can pull the same URLs out, you can try this expression:

```
var expression = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[\w.-]+\.\S{2,}/gi;
```

Comment: @HelloCW Since you said permissive is okay, I updated my answer with a simpler expression. Please be sure to accept the answer and upvote if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A permissive regular expression may be the following:

```
var expression = /(https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*/
```

This expression is simpler and easier to debug. Furthermore, it will match any website, including the ones with query params (`example.com?param=value`) or with no ASCII characters (`example.com/你好`).

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/RtLmq4/1) you can see a test.

On the other hand, it will match things that aren't websites as soon as they contain a dot, so things like `foo.bar` will be matched. However, there is no reliable way to detect whether strings like `foo.bar` are actually websites.

Comment: Thanks! but `var url_array = links.match(expression);` is only filled with one URL when I use your `var expression = /(https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*/`.

Comment: Because you have to put the flags `mgi`: `/(https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*/mgi`